# How gl.glTranslatef() affect on a specific vertex coordinate?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I have a 3D cube (8 vertices), stored in `gl.glCallList(i)` (`i` position) , which each `display()` calling changes its  vertices location by a constant (for all its x,y,z locations) using  `gl.glTranslatef()`  -

```
float tranX , tranY , tranZ ; 
public void display(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) {
    final GL gl = gLDrawable.getGL();
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(tranX ,tranY ,tranZ);
    gl.glCallList(i);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    tranX += 0.05;
    tranY += 0.05;
    tranZ += 0.05;
}
```

Let's look at a specific vertex , composed of x , y and z  , how its coordinate would be affected after a single `gl.glTranslatef(tranX ,tranY ,tranZ )` calling  ?

I need it in order to know the new coordinate locations of the cube  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read this tutorial first: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html

Vertices stored in the display list are pushed to the GPU and are transformed by model view and projection matrices. Your code uses fixed pipeline (old OpenGL) and those transformations are "magically" done by GL for you.

If you want to calculate final position of vertices you have to multiply position of a vertex (each vertex) by a desired matrix.

```
for (i = 0; i < vertex_list.length; ++i)
    v_transformed[i] = transformation_matrix * vertex_list[i]
```

Comment: So for `gl.glTranslatef(tranX ,tranY ,tranZ)` what is the `transformation_matrix` ?

Comment: @URL87 http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_matrix.html, matrix is 4x4 array of floats usually, in your case you can translate objects by simply addig transX, transY, transZ to position of vertices.